# Error when trying to display image in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I was trying to create and display an empty image to edit and update later on. This code worked when not using tkinter, just the image display. When i run the following code:

```
from random import randint
from time import *
from PIL import Image as Img
from PIL import ImageTk as ImgTk
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
main.geometry('1001x1001')
width, height = map(int, input('width and height\n').split())
canvas = Canvas(main, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()
next_cells = []
img = Img.new('RGB', (width, height))
pix = img.load()
tkpix = ImgTk.PhotoImage(pix)
imgsprite = canvas.create_image(width,height,image=pix)
main.mainloop()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Applications/eeie", line 14, in <module>
  tkpix = ImgTk.PhotoImage(pix)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
  mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 275, in getmodebase
  return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageMode.py", line 64, in getmode
  return _modes[mode]

builtins.KeyError: <PixelAccess object at 0x108aa4790>
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: The return value from `img.load()` isn't something you can pass to `PhotoImage`; you want to use the original `img` from `Img.new()`.

Comment: @jasonharper changed `PhotoImage(pix)` to `PhotoImage(img)` , now get a `_tkinter.TclError: image "<PixelAccess object at 0x10354d790>" doesn't exist` error

Comment: @Dion: May i see the output of `print((width, height))`

Comment: @stovfl: its whatever two numbers you enter into the console, no problem with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, description in code.

```
from tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk

# create canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack()
# create image object
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color='red')
new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
# load into canvas
canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=new_image, anchor=NW)
mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

To update canvas create function, and update root after changes to the object are made.

```
from tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import time


def update_position():
    while True:
        canvas.move(rectangle, 30, 10)
        time.sleep(1)
        root.update()


root = Tk()
# create canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack()
# create image object
img = Image.new('RGB', (60, 30), color='red')
new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
# load into canvas
rectangle = canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=new_image, anchor=NW)
update_position()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! it actually displays something now. If , lets say, i wanted to update the picture later on in a cycle, how would i be able to that?

Comment: @Dion There you go. If my response was useful to you will be nice if you accept it and give arrow up

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted, but since i'm on a new account it doesn't show publicly, but still counts towards your stats.